# MileWideBack (Firefox extension) and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser-addons, firefox, milewideback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you force Firefox to let a “not  compatible” plug-in run? — MileWideBack](https://superuser.com/questions/99619/can-you-force-firefox-to-let-a-not-compatible-plug-in-run--milewideback)

I updated to Windows 7 Pro (from Vista) last night, and after re-installing Firefox, found that the extension I use the most (and practically rely on) is not working (it is "compatible" according to Firefox, just not doing anything). [MileWideBack](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/334) basically turns the far left of the screen into a giant Back button (which also allows tab switching and closing using a mouse wheel). I've used this extension for about 4 or 5 years now (I think) so being stuck without it is quite a pain.

The page at addons.mozilla.org says that the extension hasn't been updated since October 2006, so I'm not hopeful for a fix to come out any time soon. Also- one other reviewer says that they're experiencing a similar problem (on Windows 7 Ultimate). I've tried disabling all other extensions to see if there were any conflicts, but it hasn't worked.

I'm wondering if anyone knows WHY this is happening with Windows 7, and if anyone has any ideas how to go about fixing it? If not, I'm thinking it might be easy (ish) to replicate it (maybe using Jetpack) and would appreciate any pointers on how to go about doing that...

Comment: @Dt7 - This is a duplicate of the question linked below. I had the same *exact* problem and got a fix here. Check it out - *Can you force Firefox to let a “not compatible” plug-in run? MileWideBack* - http://superuser.com/questions/99619/can-you-force-firefox-to-let-a-not-compatable-plug-in-run-milewideback

Comment: Firefox is saying that the extension is compatible, it's just not working. I've set both of those variables just in case, but it's still not working...

Comment: After upgrading, Firefox 3.6 said that this extension was not compatible, so it was disabled. With the changes listed in the "accepted" answer, the add-on is running just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it- had to uninstall Firefox 3.6, then install 3.5.7, install the extension, then upgrade back to 3.6. Somehow, that works.