# Force Firefox to install add-on

Tags: firefox, compatibility, firefox-extensions

I wanted to install a new add-on in Firefox – Firesheep, but when I tried to do so (from an `xpi` file), it told me that it can be installed because it's incompatible for 4.0.1.

However, compatibility check is disabled. Is there any way to force the add-on to install?

Comment: Related: [Can you force Firefox to let a “not compatible” plug-in run?](http://superuser.com/questions/99619/can-you-force-firefox-to-let-a-not-compatible-plug-in-run-milewideback)

Comment: as I said, compatibility check is disabled. (same way)

Comment: I know, that's why I said "related" and not "duplicate" :)

Comment: Have you discovered an answer? I am having the same issue, I am using the add-on compatibility reporter yet I cannot get an add-on to install...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/). With this extension Firefox will install all extensions whether they are compatible or not. Additionally from the Addons Manager you can report (if you want) if a given extension is incompatible with the current version of Firefox or report bugs.

Comment: Thanks. However, it didn't work out. It just showed the same thing as before (maybe because that add-on does not check installs from files?), however I can't find Firesheep anywhere in official add-on database

Comment: With this you just can force Firefox to install any extension, but not to force the compatibility.

Comment: This doesn't work since firefox 10.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I'm concerned you can "hack" an `xpi` file to change the maximum version required.

1. Rename the `xpi` to `zip` and extract it with your favorite unarchiving software
2. Find the `install.rdf` file and open it in a text editor
3. Change the following line (if you're talking about [this Firesheep](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/downloads)):

   ```
   <em:maxVersion>3.6.*</em:maxVersion>
   ```
4. to that one:

   ```
   <em:maxVersion>4.0.1</em:maxVersion>
   ```
5. Save the file and zip the whole folder again.
6. Rename the `zip` into `xpi` and try to install the add-on again.

Note that this does not necessarily make the add-on *work*, but it should at least install.

Comment: I tried to change that too, I changed that to 5.0.*

Comment: Hm, should have mentioned in your question then! :) I don't know, this has worked for me once.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, here are some links to download previous versions of Firefox: 
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

You'll probably want version 3.6: 
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/3.6/win32/en-US/

Comment: This is a very old version of Firefox, and the question itself is probably no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

download this version of mozila, it should work perfectly :
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/3.6.28/win32/en-GB/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.